# Copy Worksheets from Excel Files

Tags: vba, excel

i have the following Problem. I have an Excel file which already has some worksheets, lets call it my main file, and in a subdirectory i have five other Excel files each containing one sheet. Now i need to copy the contents of the excel files to my main file and in my main file there needs to be a sheet for every file in the subdirectory.

I am new to VBA so this isn't so easy for me but i got the following:

```
Sub Makro1()

Dim objWorkbook As Workbook
Dim mybook As Workbook
Set basebook = ThisWorkbook

Dim strPath As String
strPath = ThisWorkbook.Path + "\data"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFso.GetFolder(strPath)

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

If objFso.GetExtensionName(objFile.Path) = "xls" Then

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(objFile.Path)
objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Copy
Set ws = basebook.Sheets.Add
ws.Paste

objWorkbook.Close
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing


End If

Next

objExcel.Quit

End Sub
```

So it creates the sheets in my main file but it doesnot paste the the content of the files in the subdirectory into these sheets but the ast thing i copied with Ctrl+C.

I would be thankful for a solution or a hint.

Thanks in advance
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to copy the data from your source sheet to your destination sheet. Here is some example code from a VBA project:

```
Dim wbDest As Workbook
Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim shDest As Worksheet
Dim shSource As Worksheet

Set wbDest = Workbooks("Missing_Paper_Spreadsheet.xlsm")
Set wbSource = Workbooks("Missing_Paper_Assist.xls")

Set shDest = wbDest.Sheets("Weekly")
Set shSource = wbSource.Sheets("Main")

Dim rngNumUnits As Range

Set rngNumUnits = shSource.Range("A9:A50")
```

You see the last line, where it says "shSource.Range()"? You can access the cells on a worksheet by utilizing .Range(). To do what you are trying to do, you can assign a Range of cells from one worksheet to a variable, and then copy those range values to cells on a different worksheet.

Comment: Thank you very much. I ended up using `objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Copy` because i do not know in advance how big the worksheets are but now it is working very well. Thank you again